# Is 会いたくなる　one way to say "I miss you?" [連絡とったら、会いたくなるやん] What is the nuanced meaning of 会いたくなる in this context?

Tags: nuances, set-phrases, japanese-to-english

I know that there is no direct translation for "I miss you" in Japanese. I am wondering if the nuanced understanding of 連絡とったら、会いたくなる indicates that it is too painful to contact because it leads to missing one another. Am I understanding the nuance of 会いたい correctly in the context here?

Answer (score 1):

I think "連絡とったら、会いたくなるやん" is a line that expresses the "sadness" that comes with contacting you, rather than "会いたい". ("Wistfulness"("切なさ") can be thought of as synonymous with "adoration."("思慕"))

Contacting them makes you want to see them, but you don't want to see them because it's not possible. It's like a struggle between "wanting to see you" and "wistfulness of not seeing you".

Of course, this includes the feeling of wanting to meet("会いたい"), but the "やん" represents the meaning of the question, which is a question that asks the other person and oneself to agree. This suggests a strong willingness to share the wistfulness.

---

"やん" : ka-skipped words.（"やんか" → "やん"）